# I want to add custom image icon all parent categories in Magento 2

Tags: html, magento, icons, glyphicons

I need some help to add an image icon in Category layer. Please see the image below. I just want to add an icon like the image below.

I am going to share my code below what I have created for. Now I am using font awesome icon. but I want to add image. please send me code and file path

[image]

```
<div class="block-vmagicmenu-content">
    <ul class="nav-desktop vmagicmenu-narrow clearfix">
        <?php echo $vdrawHomeMenu ?>
        <?php 
            $vdrawMainMenu = str_replace('Kikinben Launching Offer', '<i class="fa fa-tablet fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Kikinben Launching Offer', $vdrawMainMenu);
            $vdrawMainMenu = str_replace('Phones, Tablets & Accessories', '<i class="fa fa-tablet fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; Phones, Tablets & Accessories', $vdrawMainMenu);
            $vdrawMainMenu = str_replace('Computers & Electronics', '<i class="fa fa-laptop fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; Computers & Electronics', $vdrawMainMenu);
            $vdrawMainMenu = str_replace('TV, Audio & Gaming', '<i class="fa fa-desktop" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; TV, Audio & Gaming', $vdrawMainMenu);

            $vdrawMainMenu = str_replace('Makeup & Glam', '<i class="fa fa-paint-brush " aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; Makeup & Glam', $vdrawMainMenu);

            $vdrawMainMenu = str_replace('Men\'s Fashion', '<i class="fa fa-male fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; Men\'s Fashion', $vdrawMainMenu);
            $vdrawMainMenu = str_replace('Women\'s Fashion', '<i class="fa fa-female fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; Women\'s Fashion', $vdrawMainMenu);
            $vdrawMainMenu = str_replace('Toys, Kids & Baby', '<i class="fa fa-futbol-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; Toys, Kids & Baby', $vdrawMainMenu);
            $vdrawMainMenu = str_replace('Kitchen & Home Appliances', '<i class="fa fa-cutlery fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; Kitchen & Home Appliances', $vdrawMainMenu);
            $vdrawMainMenu = str_replace('Home & Decor', '<i class="fa fa-bed fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; Home & Decor', $vdrawMainMenu);
            $vdrawMainMenu = str_replace('Car & Motorbike', '<i class="fa fa-car" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; Car & Motorbike', $vdrawMainMenu);
            $vdrawMainMenu = str_replace('Building & Constructions', '<i class="fa fa-building-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; Building & Constructions', $vdrawMainMenu);
            $vdrawMainMenu = str_replace('Beauty & Fragrances', '<i class="fa fa-magic fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; Beauty & Fragrances', $vdrawMainMenu);
            echo $vdrawMainMenu 
        ?>
        <?php echo $vdrawExtraMenu ?>
    </ul>
    <div class="all-cat"><span><?php echo __('All Categories')?></span><span style="display:none"><?php echo __('Close')?></span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please click on {enter image description here to see image}